# How i can refresh model's attributes when invoke save using backbone

Tags: javascript, ajax, backbone.js

How i can refresh model's attributes when invoke save()
I am using backbone and backbone relational. Have the following code:

```
saveParams: function(event){
    var self = this;
    this.model.save({}, {
      success: function(model, resp, xhr){
        model = ...

      },
      error: function(model, resp){
        alert(JSON.stringify(resp));
      }
    });
    $(this.el).effect("highlight", {}, 1000);
    event.preventDefault();
  },
```

When pass callback success, the parameters "model" has ald attributes (before save), resp is holding updated attributes. How i can update attributes in a model?

model.set(resp) doesn' help me
model.set(JSON.stringify) doesn't help me

UPD1: I use Backbone RelationModel cause have nested models. Nested models doesn't refresh when success callback invokes. I guess because RelationModel using Backbone.Store.

UPD2: For me works only this:

```
model.clear()
model.set(resp);
model.change();
```

I know it's ugly, but it's working )

Answer (score 2):

Normally you don't have to do this! 
Backbone automatically parses the response if a save() command, as you can see here:
http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/docs/backbone.html#section-41

If your response data differs from the default assumed backbone data structure you should take a look at the `Backbone.Model#parse` method and maybe overwrite it (it's a very simple method).

Comment: Yeah, anything passed in a response will be assigned to model. It has to be in proper data structure as chris_b says. Not only that existing attributes will be replaced with new ones, but any new non-existing attribute will be added to model's attribute hash.

Comment: Hmm. Maybe I'm retarded but I don't see anything in the linked docs that's actually about the `save()` function (it's about `set()`), and the automatic parsing isn't working for me.

Comment: Keep in mind that this answer is from 2011 - probably for Backbone 0.5. I guess they changed the behavior in the current version. (see Backbone Changelog)